# Looking for "Call+ verb" structure, which doesn't have a real meaning of using any voice necessarily

Tags: collocations

Looking for a collocation or an idiom that contains the word 'Call', which doesn't have **a real meaning of using voice** necessarily (except for call on the phone) but metaphorical. Is there such collocation in English?

For example:
Give-up (give + preposition) doesn't really mean to give something by hand.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to say with that structure?

Comment: Can you even give an example of that structure. “He calls be” does not even seem possible in English.

Comment: I edited my question. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: No I still don't understand.  Can you give a complete example of a sentence which uses "call + verb".    Then can you give a clearer description of what you want to say.  Finally you need to explain why you need to use "call + verb".  Is it a word game?

Comment: I edited it again. Now is it understood?

Comment: Perhaps call up, meaning conscript. Also call and call in, meaning visit. A call out for an appliance serviceman can be done by SMS or email.

Comment: I have to concur that the question simply doesn't make sense. What are you asking when you say "Call+"? The word "call" is not sensible in the context you've set it in. Next, the phrase "a real meaning of using any voice" simply does not make sense (nor does "to call by mouth").  As well, "give up" is normally not hyphenated, and actually does mean to give something, particularly in the sense of surrendering (whether an object or an objective).

Comment: I took your notes and enhanced my question.

Comment: I would **call** your question an odd one. That is a use of **call** that doesn't require use of the voice, because it means "to identify or to name". But it isn't "call + verb structure". There, **call** is a verb. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. So the verb 'call' by itself can be abstract. I didn't know that. Thank you

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Do you know where I can find a reference for this usage that you mentioned? I've checked the dictionary and I couldn't find one. See here for example: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call

Comment: @JudiciousAllure At your reference, the very first definition starts with "to give someone or something a name". You can give something a name in writing or in a publication without using your voice.